# Tomcat 8 SSL certificate - newbie

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I  need to configure SSL\TLS (https) on Tomcat 8.

I've done this previously where I've:

- Created a keystore
- Generated a CSR
- Sent the CSR off and received a .p7b back
- Imported into the keystore
- Configured Tomcat to use this keystore

This time, from scratch, I've actually been given:

- one .p12 file
- one pem file
- one .pse file
- one .cer file no passwords

The .PEM looks like it contains the PrivateKey entry and the full chain certificate.

How do I go about configuring Tomcat to use the above? I've tried a bunch of things and don't really understand the concepts beyond the basics.